# Limit Node express to specific hostnames?

Tags: node.js

What's the best way to reject requests to my web server (running via Node express) that are coming in to an unrecognized hostname? I.e. I only want to respond to requests that are intended for my domain, not for requests that are just aimed at my IP address.

Comment: When you say reject, I assume you mean return a 404 or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use the connect [`vhost`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html) middleware.

Where you would normally do this:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.send('HI');
});

app.listen(80);
```

You would do this:

```
var vhostApp = express();
vhostApp.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.send('HI');
});

var app = express();
app.use(express.vhost('example.com', vhostApp));
app.listen(80);
```